# Setting Sql datasource using JSTL Tag in JSP

Tags: servlets, jstl, vs-web-application-project

Weeks before I developed a simple web application using JSP servlets. After reading through various sites, came to know that the Scriptlets should be completely avoided in jsp [view].

Hence, I am trying to convert to JSTL. While setting the SQL data source whose context are available in the `web.xml`. Things not worked. Also, how can I avoid mentioning the db user credentials explictly in the JSTL code. If any best way, please share. Thanks in Advance

### JSTL connecting MySQL

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql"%>    

<sql:setDataSource 
    var="datasource"
    driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    url=${initParam['dbURL']
    user=${initParam['dbUser']} 
    pass=${initParam['dbPass']}/>
```

### Web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>dbUser</param-name>
    <param-value>root</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>dbPassword</param-name>
    <param-value>root</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>dbURL</param-name>
    <param-value>jdbc:mysql://xxx.xxx.xxx:3306/client_db</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4j-config</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/log4j.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/AppErrorHandler</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
    <location>/AppErrorHandler</location>
</error-page>

<filter>
    <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.schoolmanager.servlet.filters.AuthenticationFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right it is really not good idea to store db parameters in JSP page. Also official Java EE documentation approve  it:

> The JSTL SQL tags for accessing databases listed in Table 7-7 are
>   designed for quick prototyping and simple applications. For production
>   applications, database operations are normally encapsulated in
>   JavaBeans components.

The general idea to store you connection parametrs in xml or Java files and execute all db specific operations in plain Java. To get this conception check [example](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/mysql-connector-for-java-how-to-install-in-eclipse-and-tomcat/).